# RedisException Connection refused on http://localhost:80/

Tags: docker, redis, laravel-sail

I am trying to run an existing laravel project on my localhost. I cloned the project and I installed wsl2 and docker desktop on my windows 10 system. when I execute sail up command, all containers build well and I dont have any errors but in my brrowser I have this error:
RedisException
Connection refused
http://localhost/
here is my docker-compose.yml :

> ```
> # For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
> ```

```
  version: '3'
  services:
  laravel.test:
    build:
        context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
            WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
    image: sail-8.0/app
    ports:
        - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
    environment:
        WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
        LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
    volumes:
        - '.:/var/www/html'
    networks:
        - sail
    depends_on:
        - mysql
        # - pgsql
        - redis
        # - selenium
  # selenium:
  #     image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
  #     volumes:
  #         - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
  #     networks:
  #         - sail
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
        - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
#    pgsql:
#        image: postgres:13
#        ports:
#            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
#        environment:
#            PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
#            POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
#            POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
#            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
#        volumes:
#            - 'sailpostgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
#        networks:
#            - sail
#        healthcheck:
#          test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${DB_DATABASE}", "-U", "${DB_USERNAME}"]
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
# memcached:
#     image: 'memcached:alpine'
#     ports:
#         - '11211:11211'
#     networks:
#         - sail
mailhog:
    image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
        - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
    networks:
        - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
#    sailpostgresql:
#        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

can you please help me. I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use service name as host not localhost. Like `http://redis`

Comment: I am new in docker can you please explain me more what do you mean?

Comment: In your application you need to define redis hostname as `http://redis:6379` not `http://localhost:6379`